# How do I check whether ArrayList of the associated key contains a string of interest?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have `LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> h`

If I do this: `System.out.println(h.get("key1"))`; it prints out this: `[Burger King]`

But if I do this:

```
if (h.get("key1").contains("Burger"))
    System.out.println("Key1 contains Burger");
```

It ignores it. How do I check for a particular string in the ArrayList of the associated key?

Comment: By `results`, do you mean `h`?

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad...edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List.contains() looks for an exact matching element.

Do you mean this?

```
for(String s: results.get("key1")) 
  if(s.contains("Burger"))
    System.out.println("Key1 contains Burger");
```

Answer (score 4):

**ArrayList.contains**() *Returns true if this list contains the specified element.*

In your case it doesn't contain "Burger", but it contains "Burger King", the matching is identical not on subtrings.

To achieve what you want you've to loop on the ArrayList and check each element with **String.contains**() applied on the String which is defined as "*Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values*".

If you want also to ignore the case you can apply **String.toLowerCase**() to your search term and to each element before applying String.contains().

Answer (score 1):

you are testing a list for inclusion of a partial string, which will not work, since the actual values is "Burger King".  You need to call `contains()` on each element of the ArrayList if you want to check for a partial match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over all `String` objects in the `ArrayList<String>` and call **their** `contains()` method:

```
boolean containsSubString(final Collection<String> strings, final String searchString) {
  for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.contains(searchString)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The List contains the String `Burger King` and you are looking for the String `Burger`. Hence no output.